# Add field of similar data with percentage in database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, triggers, full-text-search

I am working on a scraping task where I have to collect products title and prices from two websites. I have the large dataset after scraping and the structure of the table:

```json
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "ProductA",
  "price": 10,
  "matches": []
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "ProductB",
  "price": 20,
  "matches": []
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "title": "Another One",
  "price": 30,
  "matches": []
},
]
```

I am using **MongoDB** right now as a Database. I have to run some script that will find **the matches products with a score** and store it in the column within a large dataset. Example:

```json
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "ProductA",
  "price": 10,
  "matches": [{score: 0.75, productId: 2}]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "ProductB",
  "price": 20,
  "matches": [{score: 0.75, productId: 1}]
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "title": "Another One",
  "price": 30,
  "matches": []
},
]
```

I tried `LIKE` in `SQL` and `$text` in `MongoDB` but both are working only when I have to find similarities with a specific text.

Is there any built-in operation in DB that can go thru all the documents and find similarities by `title`, generate a percentage of how much it matches, and then add it in the `matches` field?

**NOTE**: MongoDB is not mandatory, any database can be mentioned.

Comment: It's unclear what query you're asking really. could you try to rephrase it somehow?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I updated the question, please read the last paragraph.